# Grammar check and words

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs, adverbs, expressions

I am new to reading fantasy and fiction books. 
I am writing one which is called Fable & Coins which is about a merchant called Yohan who is heading through a city called Yarren, where a rite has been set up on it for the past 2 days.

Is there anything wrong with that sentence? Thanks!

I want it to have a nice flow and no typos.

Comment: You edited the original phrase such that neither the question I posed for you nor the edited title of the post made any sense, so I rolled back to your original question. Decide what you are asking - specifically - and ask it. _"Is anything wrong with that sentence"_ is not on-topic on this site.

Comment: Not to mention, there are two sentences. The main thing odd about these sentences is : why would anyonde who was "new to reading fantasy and fiction" books consider writing one ? That, and the fact that fantasy is a sub-genre of fiction, so "and" is odd. I suggest you find an editor or co-writer who is more fluent in English if you wish your novel to be read. Best of luck.

Comment: [Lang-8](http://lang-8.com) is a great proofreading site. If you would explain why you are unsure that your sentence is correct or identify some specific part that's troubling you, it might be on-topic here, otherwise it would be better to ask your question on Lang-8.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am new to reading fantasy and fiction books, I am writing one called Fable and Coins. In this story a merchant called Yohan goes through Yarren, a city that has had rites for the past two days.

• You need to make it have a flow
• The sentence that you made is okay, but it doesn't have a nice flow to it

Comment: Yeah, I will rewrite my question!                            • • You need to make it have a flow.